# I want to group in sql oracle diferent rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pentaho

i want by group by 'Facturacion' and Motor Facturación Drools. I have this sql:

```
SELECT c.cname                   AS componente, 
       w.timeworked / 3600       AS horas, 
       Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) 
         OVER ()                 AS sum_tipo, 
       Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY c.cname) AS sum_by_component 
FROM   jira.jiraissue j, 
       jira.worklog w, 
       jira.project p, 
       jira.issuetype t, 
       jira.component c, 
       jira.nodeassociation na 
WHERE  w.issueid = j.id 
       AND J.project = P.id 
       AND na.source_node_id = j.id 
       AND na.sink_node_entity = 'Component' 
       AND na.source_node_entity = 'Issue' 
       AND na.sink_node_id = c.id 
       AND t.id = j.issuetype 
       AND p.pname = 'Area Económica' 
       AND t.pname = 'Bug' 
       AND w.startdate BETWEEN To_date('01/10/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND 
                               To_date('09/10/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

the result is this:

[image]

if i put a select distinct, it grouped ok but some lines doesn't catch. the result is this:[image]

i want quit the column HORAS and only watch 2 rows

Comment: could you please provide a sample of your desired output please. it is not clear to me how the result should look. ty

Comment: do you want remove column horas?

Comment: Can you also show us the expected output?  Also, please try to edit your question and include the data as _text_, not as images (though your particular images are quite readable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use distinct

```
SELECT distinct c.cname AS componente,             
       Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) OVER ()  AS sum_tipo, 
       Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) 
     OVER ( 
       partition BY c.cname) AS sum_by_component 
FROM   jira.jiraissue j, 
       jira.worklog w, 
       jira.project p, 
       jira.issuetype t, 
       jira.component c, 
       jira.nodeassociation na 
WHERE  w.issueid = j.id 
       AND J.project = P.id 
       AND na.source_node_id = j.id 
       AND na.sink_node_entity = 'Component' 
       AND na.source_node_entity = 'Issue' 
       AND na.sink_node_id = c.id 
       AND t.id = j.issuetype 
       AND p.pname = 'Area Económica' 
       AND t.pname = 'Bug' 
       AND w.startdate BETWEEN To_date('01/10/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND 
                               To_date('09/10/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have answered in your question itself Since you want to quit the column hora, remove below line from select and use distinct.

```
  w.timeworked / 3600       AS horas,
```